# Nginx + Docker (Nginx + Vue JS)

Tags: nginx, docker

Есть сервер (**VDS**)

На сервере есть `nginx`.

Также на сервере крутится докер контейнер с еще одним `nginx` внутри.

#### Конфиг `nginx` в `docker`:

```
server {
        listen 8080 default_server;
        server_name _;

        location /ssb
        {
            root /var/www;
            index index.html;
        }
 }
```

#### Конфиг `nginx` на `VDS`:

```
server {
                listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
                listen 443 ssl;
                server_name xxx.ru www.xxx.ru;
                ssl_certificate /...;
                ssl_certificate_key /...;
                include /...;
                ssl_dhparam /...;
                access_log   /...;
                root /var/www/xxx;

        location / {
                root /var/www/xxx/index;
                index index.html;
        }

        location /ssb {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }


}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name xxx.ru www.xxx.ru;

        
    if ($host = www.xxx.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    if ($host = xxx.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

 }
```

#### `Docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  frontend:
    image: sfront
    build: ./frontend
    command: nginx -g daemon off
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend
    network_mode: host

  backend:
    image: sbackend
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: php -S localhost:8000
    restart: always
```

При переходе на `https://xxx.ru/ssb` получаю редирект на `http://xxx.ru:8080/ssb`, на котором пустая страница.

Хотя по `Network` файлы грузятся.

В чём проблема?